# type casting the arguments of a function

Tags: c++

If the code is like the below,

```
void func(std::string str)
{
    ...
}

void main()
{
    std::string p1 = "abcd";
    char p2[SOME_LENGTH] = "abcd";

    func(p1); // (1)
    func(p2); // (2)
}
```

which way is efficient between (1) and (2)?

Comment: `func("abcd");` is the best

Comment: Efficient in what sense ?

Comment: `main` must have a return type of `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are equally efficient/inefficient. Both involves copying the string and using the copy as the value of the argument 'str'. A better way would be declaring func as

```
void func(const std::string &str) {
}
```

This can avoid copying of the string.

Comment: This might be less efficient , depending on what `func` does with the string. For example if `func` intended to modify its copy of the string.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that 'str' is not changed in func().